# Using draper gem with devise registration controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, draper

**I have declared user_decorator.rb instead of user_helper.rb in the following way**

```
class UserDecorator < Draper::Decorator
   delegate_all

  def contract_type
    contract_types.keys.collect {|k| [k.humanize, k]}
  end
  def employee_type
    employee_types.keys.collect {|k| [k.humanize, k]}
  end

  def department_role
    department_roles.keys.collect {|k| [k.humanize, k]}
  end
end
```

and here are my enums that are declared on the user.rb

```
 enum contract_type: [:probationary, :apprenticeship, :six_months_to_one_year,
    :three_years]
  enum department_role: [:ceo, :cto, :coo, :manager, :tl, :gl, :developer]
  enum employee_type: [:full_time, :part_time, :internship]
```

I want to call the helper method from the view that is related to registrations controller. It is like as

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def new
    super
  end

  def create
    super
  end
end
```

But if I call the helper method, like as following from the views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb

```
<%= f.select :contract_type, contract_type, {prompt: t(".contract_type",
      default: "Select contract type")} %>
```

It don't find the contract_type. Need help about how I can access the helper methods from the view that is declared on the user_decorator.rb

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

In order to get a decorated user object from Devise's `current_user` method, [you can override it](https://ariejan.net/2012/04/14/decorating-devise-s-current_user-with-draper/):

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def current_user
    UserDecorator.decorate(super) unless super.nil?
  end
end
```

However, since your issue is on the `devise/registrations/new.html.erb` page, at this point a user will not have logged in and hence won't have a any kind of decorated `current_user` object.

So, what it would seem you want is to get the set of decorated contract types from your `User` model into that view, which you could do by creating an instance variable on the controller:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def new
    @contract_types = User.contract_types.keys.collect {|k| [k.humanize, k]}
    super
  end
end
```

and then use it in the view:

```
<%= f.select :contract_type, 
             @contract_types,
             { prompt: t(".contract_type", default: "Select contract type") } %>
```

If you wanted to do further refactorings, you could perhaps create a scope-like class method on your `User` model that does the decoration of the contract types:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.humanized_contract_types
    contract_types.keys.collect {|k| [k.humanize, k]}
  end
end
```

So, then your controller code could be shortened to:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def new
    @contract_types = User.humanized_contract_types
    super
  end
end
```

Or, if you're intent on using the `UserDecorator` class, you could look into [proxying class method calls to it](https://github.com/drapergem/draper#proxying-class-methods).

Answer (score 0):

You can override your `new` method to decorate your resource like so :

```
# registrations_controller.rb

def new
  build_resource({})
  yield resource if block_given?
  respond_with resource
end

protected

def build_resource(hash = nil)
  self.resource = resource_class.new_with_session(hash || {}, session).decorate
end
```